# python convert log file into html format

Tags: python

I am new to python programming part.Someone help me here that would be great.

I am converting my below (test1.log)log output to (test1.html)html using python send as html email.

I have already created python code to send email. now i need to convert the log into html format and add that html file into python_send_email script. Now I need help here how to convert this test1.log output to test.html.

```
test1.log :
--------------

Process: Failed:  threshold limit is high

Memory : Failed: Exceed threshold limit

Disk usage: Failed: Disk size exceeded than 75% size

Swap Memory - host1-sos1 :Passed 

Swap Memory -host2-os2 :Passed 

Swap Memory -host3-os3 :Passed

****************************
    Detailed error
***************************
---------- Disk usage ------------------
NAME          Disk Total(GB)       Disk usage(%)                    
---------- --------------------    ----------------                 
host1-os1          758                 89%     


Email should send html format as below:
---------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------
|  Task name   |    Status           | Failed Reason    |              
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Process      |    Failed               | threshold limit is high|
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| Memory       |    Failed               | Exceed threshold limit  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| Disk Usage   |    Failed              | Disk size exceeded than 75% size|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Swap Memory - host1-sos1  |    Passed               |                    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Swap Memory - host2-sos2  |    Passed               |                    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Swap Memory - host3-sos3  |    Passed               |                    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

***************************
      Detailed error
***************************
---------- Diskusage --------------
NAME              OPEN_MODE            DATABASE_ROLE                    
---------- --------------------      ----------------                 
host1-os1      READ ONLY WITH APPLY   PHYSICAL STANDBY
```

I tried to reach with below code to convert log into html format:

CODE:

```
contents = open("test1.log","r")
        with open("test1.html", "w") as e:
                e.write("<table>")
                for lines in contents.readlines():
                    a,b,c = [ str(x) for x in lines.split(':')]
                    if '*****' in lines:
                         break
                    else:
                         e.write("<tr><tb>%s</tr><tr><tb>%s</tr></tb><tr><tb>%s</tr></tb>\n"%(a,b,c))
               e.write("</table>\n")
```

but it's not working .Need your help here.

Comment: not enough information. Need error message, and / or  input file.

Comment: input file is - test1.log

Comment: how is it not working?  I see two problems right away.  You are only going to output the lines before the first line containing `'*****'`, because when you match that string in a line, you call `break`, which ends processing of the data.  I think you meant `continue` rather than `break`.  Second, your `<tr>` and `<tb>` HTML tags don't seem to be nested properly and you're missing one `</tb>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's the code. I hardcoded a value but, it's enough to get started.

```
 contents = open("./sample_data/test1.log","r")
 with open("test1.html", "w") as e:
   e.write("<table>")
   for lines in contents.readlines():
      print(len(lines.split(':')))
      if '*****' in lines:
        break 

      if(len(lines.split(':')) == 3):
        a, b, c = [str(x) for x in lines.split(':')]
        e.write("<tr><tb>%s</tr><tr><tb>%s</tr></tb><tr><tb>%s</tr></tb>\n"%(a,b,c))
        e.write("</table>\n")
 e.close()
```

Here's the colab link if you want to modify before integrating.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZNjA7UBx7BD6Yi_A5TDcxwgeod_Y6Eoo?usp=sharing

**NOTE** Be sure to change the the file location for log

[image]

Comment: Thanks its working .. what about the  ` Swap Memory - host1-sos1 :Passed 

Swap Memory -host2-os2 :Passed 

Swap Memory -host3-os3 :Passed`
 this lines in the log. also remaining detailed log also i need to append to this html.

Comment: Please don't put thanks/pleas for accepts, etc. in your answers.

Comment: why ?, if the answer is helpful and they agree ?